# Indexing a cell array with variable number of dimensions with a vector

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

In MATLAB, have an *N*-dimensional cell `C`, where *N* is an integer only determined at runtime. How do I access a specific element of `C` with a vector variable `id`? For example, with `N=3` and `id=[1,5,2]`, how to programmatically get the content of `c{1,5,2}`? I cannot hard-code it as `c{id(1),id(2),id(3)}` since `N` is only fixed at runtime.

Comment: Does `c{id}` not work?

Comment: @thewaywewalk no, c{id} returns c{id(1)}, c{id(2)},..., c{(id(N))}

Comment: well, `C{[id(1),id(2),id(3)]}` and `C{id}` are equivalent.

Comment: @thewaywewalk ...but very different from `c{id(1),id(2),id(3)}`

Comment: @Dan ... which for the input I Imagined is not working at all, the same stands for your answer. For me the question is totally unclear. But your mentalist skills seemed good enough and the OP is satisfied. So why not...

Comment: @thewaywewalk think of an input like `C = num2cell(rand(8,8,8))` for example (assuming `N=3`), although `C` could contain anything really, so long as it has `N` dimensions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `id` is a cell array, then you can use [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) for this by taking advantage of the [comma separated list syntax](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) ,i.e. `{:}`, to send a variable number of inputs to `sub2ind`

```
id = {1,5,2};
ind = sub2ind(size(C), id{:})
c{ind}
```

if `id` isn't a cell array (and for some reason can't be created as one), then use `num2cell` to convert it.